# sudo: a password is required

Tags: bash, icinga2

I am trying to copy my ssh keys to all the hosts which my script reads from a list, ssh to them and run some `yum install` commands:

```
while read f; do
   ssh-copy-id -f myusername@"$f"
   ssh myusername@"$f" '
        yum install -y epel-release
        wget --no-check-certificate https://packages.icinga.org/epel/7/release/noarch/icinga-rpm-release-7-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
        sudo -n yum install -y icinga-rpm-release-7-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
        yum install -y icinga2  nagios-plugins-all
        rm -rf /etc/icinga2/conf.d/*
        rm -f /etc/icinga2/zones.conf
```

I get an error:

```
sudo: a password is required 
bash: line 7: /etc/icinga2/zones.conf: Permission denied
```

If I add -i (`sudo -i`) then I will get:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
bash: line 7: /etc/icinga2/zones.conf: Permission denied
```

Can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a programming question, and a common FAQ where it's on-topic. Search for the error message on [unix.se] or [su]. If you still need help, you need to be more detailed about what you expect to happen and what's configured in `sudoers`. I recall explaining this problem in response to one of your earlier questions last week.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't running any shells with `sudo`, so the `-i` option isn't necessary. What you *do* need is to drop the `-n` argument so that `sudo` can prompt you for a password, tell `ssh` to provide a terminal for `sudo` to use for the prompt, and make sure you are using `sudo` for all the commands that require it.

Something like

```
while read f; do
   ssh-copy-id -f myusername@"$f"
   ssh -t myusername@"$f" '
        sudo yum install -y epel-release
        wget --no-check-certificate https://packages.icinga.org/epel/7/release/noarch/icinga-rpm-release-7-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
        sudo yum install -y icinga-rpm-release-7-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
        sudo yum install -y icinga2  nagios-plugins-all
        sudo rm -rf /etc/icinga2/conf.d/*
        sudo rm -f /etc/icinga2/zones.conf
        '
```

Comment: adding to this answer, if you want to fully automate this, you can do ```echo "$pass" | sudo -S ... ```.

Comment: If you really want to automate this, get `expect`.

Comment: Or configure `sudo` on the remote host to run those commands without a password.

Comment: @chepner, thanks but I get this error using your solution: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

MatiasBarrios - Thank you, your solution works, but that way I'll have to send my password in plain text to each server :-(

Comment: Try with `-ntt` instead of `-t`. You'll need to redirect standard input from `/dev/null` with `-n` anyway, to prevent `ssh` from reading the rest of the loop's input before `read` can be called again, and you'll need `-tt` instead of `-t` to force a pseudoterminal to be allocated, since `ssh` doesn't have one. (It may still fail; I don't fully understand the interaction of the pseudoterminal with `sudo` in this setup.)